# How to center openlayers map from PostGIS coordinates?

Tags: postgresql, gis, openlayers, postgis

I'm trying to center my openlayers map with a coordinate obtained from my database with the PostGIS functions: `ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_SetSRID(ST_Centroid(geom),3857))`. The geometry in my database is projected in EPSG:25830 and my openlayers map is projected in EPSG:3857.

The coordinate I get on the client side once I call the server is like this:

> 613056.633587271 4738175.03852526

Then I do the following with the openlayers map's view and the coordinate received:

```
view.animate({
    center: coordinatefromserver,
    duration: 500
});
```

And my map moves to a totally different position.

The kind of coordinate that I know that works fine is this one:

> -180099.9705826787,5279777.85057039

What am I missing? PostGIS functions? Any type conversion? Projections? Sorry, but I'm pretty noobie in this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the problem is that your query is not doing what you want. If you want to transform from one srid to another you need to use [st_transform](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) and not st_setsrid.

I.e. your query should be:

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_transform(ST_Centroid(geom),3857))
```

Answer (score 3):

When transformed from EPSG:25830 to EPSG:3857 those coordinates produce [-180081.82283603796, 5279725.360517778] so the server is returning EPSG:25830 despite the SetSRID 3857.

You can do the transform in OpenLayers:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:25830', '+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ');

if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); }  // only needed for OL5

view.animate({
    center: ol.proj.transform(coordinatefromserver, 'EPSG:25830', view.getProjection())
    duration: 500
});
```

Comment: You were right! But I finally transformed the coordinate on the server side, thanks.